# performing elem.click(); in a javascript loop doesn't always work - timing?

Tags: javascript

Hello I've been working on a Javascript 8 slider puzzle (that is working including event listeners) and have code that generates an array of moves (which squares/div id's the user would click) to solve the puzzle.

My goal is for a user to be able to click on a solve button, triggering a function that will play back that array of solution moves in the puzzle.

Where I'm truly stumped is for some reason, in the following code, the click doesn't work on every iteration of the loop - which screws everything up. I'd appreciate if anybody can offer any help or suggestions.

```
while(k < moves.length)
{ 
   var move = "vp" + moves[k];
   var el = document.getElementById(move);
   el.click();  // simulate a users click on div
   populate(); // update array
   k++;
}
```

edit - for those who asked below are event functions & a little more code...

```
function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
// avoid memory overhead of new anonymous functions for every event handler that's installed
// by using local functions
function listenHandler(e) {
    var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
    if (ret === false) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    return(ret);
}

function attachHandler() {
    // set the this pointer same as addEventListener when fn is called
    // and make sure the event is passed to the fn also so that works the same too
    var ret = fn.call(elem, window.event);   
    if (ret === false) {
        window.event.returnValue = false;
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    }
    return(ret);
}

if (elem.addEventListener) {
    elem.addEventListener(event, listenHandler, false);
} else {
    elem.attachEvent("on" + event, attachHandler);
}
}

window.onload = function() {
var height = (newImg.height*0.33);
var width = (newImg.width*0.33333);

addEvent(document.getElementById('shuffle'),'click',initGame);
addEvent(document.getElementById('vp1'),'click',move);
addEvent(document.getElementById('vp2'),'click',move);
addEvent(document.getElementById('vp3'),'click',move); // ...
```

This is first part of function that el.click(); calls...

```
    function move() {

var e = this;
var id = e.id.charAt(2);

var temp = 0;
//var images = e.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
//alert(images[0].className);
if (id == 1) {
  if (document.getElementById("vp2").innerHTML.indexOf("selected") != -1)
    {    temp = e.innerHTML;
        e.innerHTML = document.getElementById("vp2").innerHTML;    
        document.getElementById("vp2").innerHTML = temp;
        numMoves++;
}else if (document.getElementById("vp4").innerHTML.indexOf("selected") != -1)
    {   temp = e.innerHTML;
        e.innerHTML = document.getElementById("vp4").innerHTML;    
        document.getElementById("vp4").innerHTML = temp;
        numMoves++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're sure `el` definitely finds an element?

Comment: How are you listening to the click event? Is this happening in all browsers?

Comment: if the click causes any type of animation then the browser would not allow the animations to queue up as fast as a `while` loop would add them

Comment: Utkanos - yes. David - I have function that adds listeners & Yes it's cross browser

Comment: jbabey - I'm pretty sure this is my problem & i've tried adding setTimeout & various types of loop - I'm at a real loss as to how to fix w\

Comment: @JimHudson could you show us output of `console.log(moves)` in firebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$(el).click();
```

Javascript:

```
var etype = 'click';
if (el.fireEvent) {
  (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
}else{
  var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
  evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
  el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
}
```

Comment: Peter, I'm not using jQuery. Anyway, I believe the issue is as jbabey said - by the time el.click completes the loop is way ahead.

Comment: Peter, after some sleep and re-reading your answer I tried the javascript portion just to see if dispatch event might help. It doesn't, the event still doesn't complete in time.

Comment: @jbaby & anybody else - I am truly stumped & have put page online hoping somebody can help http://www.thehudsons.org/slider_p4.cfm

Comment: the chk & chk2 divs are for debugging - in chk2 if a move is made then just move # shows if no move then the div id is shown. the move() always works with real click - for some reason it doesn't work consistently with simulated click or when called like move.call(el)

Comment: I need email or is there way through stacko?

Comment: @JimHudson after some debug i found your `click` event is firing every time. It's something wrong with your puzzle solver, not firing click event.

Comment: check out solveIt() and playOut() in slider.js they are what doesn't work - after refactoring a bunch, I'm not using click to call move() - also glad to send zip but not sure how through SO

Comment: @JimHudson don't mind about offline version, already got it. please [check this](http://www.a1przeprowadzki.com/puzzle/slider_p4.cfm.htm) - as you see your script is clicking at wrong chunk..

Comment: sorry Jim i won't write puzzle solver for you :) it's your job :)

Comment: THANK YOU for setting me on right track! the solver returns id of the pic slices and I was "moving" the containers for the pics. Double doh! It worked just enough to be really hard to see the error. All working now!